# Get only the new and changed files and folders

Tags: git, github, zip, archive

I want to create an update package (ZIP archive) with only the changed or new files and folders after the last release or specific commit. How can I do this with Git (my repo is on GitHub)?

Comment: Yes. Sorry mate. I have searched and could not find any good results. Maybe I used the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Using `git` you can get a list of files that have been changed between 2 revisions:

```
git diff --name-only commitish1 commitish2
```

`commitish` can be a commit, tag or any other revision identifier.

Using the list of files, you can then add them to your update archive. The following will create your update archive.

```
git diff --name-only commitish1 commitish2 | xargs zip update.zip
```

**Hint:** You need to have to checkout the correct commit first for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out later!

Comment: "xargs zip update.zip" is not working with Windows 10. Is there another way to get a Zip without installing any 3rd-party libs (except Git)?